# How to override the ToString method of ArrayList of object?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, overriding, tostring

```
class Person {
  public String firstname;
  public String lastname;
}

Person p1 = new Person("Jim","Green");
Person p2 = new Person("Tony","White");

ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

people.add(p1);
people.add(p2);

System.out.println(people.toString());
```

I'd like the output to be `[Jim,Tony]`, what is the simplest way to override the `ToString` method if such a method exists at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually need to override toString() in your Person class, which will return the firstname, because, ArrayList automatically invokes the toString of the enclosing types to print string representation of elements.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.firstname;
}
```

So, add the above method to your Person class, and probably you will get what you want.

**P.S.**: -  On a side note, you don't need to do `people.toString()`. Just do `System.out.println(people)`, it will automatically invoke the `toString()` method for `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a static helper method on the Person class:

```
public static String toString(ArrayList<Person> people) {

    Iterator<Person> iter = people.iterator();

    ....


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write override method `toString()` method in `Person` class.

```
public String toString() {
    return firstname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to override the `toString` method of Person class since arrayList just iterates the Person class instance.