# Java: I can't override toString() properly to print an arraylist when there's different classes involved

Tags: java, arraylist, overriding, tostring

This is hard to describe well but I'll do the best I can. I have an arraylist of objects. Inside those objects are attributes. Instead of everything inside one class, they are all separate classes. This is the first time I'm working with stuff like this and I'm not sure if I got the syntax right. I'm trying to make println print out the stuff inside the arraylist and not bytecode.

```
//main.java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        world w = new world();
        System.out.println(w.list);
    }
}

//world.java
public class world {
    ArrayList<object> list = new ArrayList<>;

    public void makeObjectA{
        list.add(new ObjectA())
    }
    public void makeObjectB{
        list.add(new ObjectB())
    }

    @Override public String toString () {
        ObjectA obja = new ObjectA();
        ObjectB objb = new ObjectB();
        return "A: " + obja.getattra() + ", B: " + objb.getattrb();
    }
}

//object.java
public class object {
}

//ObjectA.java
public class ObjectA extends object {
    private int attra = 10;

    public int getattra() {
        return attra;
    }
    public void setattra(int attra) {
        this.attra = attra;
    }
}

//ObjectB.java
public class ObjectB extends object {
    private String attrab = "Ten";

    public String getattrb() {
        return attrb;
    }
    public void setattrb(String attrb) {
        this.attrb = attrb;
    }
}
```

The output prints out bytecode. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (probably the syntax everywhere). Help please?

Comment: Your code wouldn't even compile at the moment, as you have `System.out.println(list);` as a statement directly in the `world` class declaration...

Comment: Your code will not compile due to `ArrayList<object> list = new ArrayList<>;`

Comment: Oh, and `ObjectB` attempts to use a variable called `attrb` which doesn't exist. *Please* post *complete* examples rather than just pseudo-code. (I'm also wondering why you'd want `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` to extend `world`... that looks odd to me.)

Comment: Sorry. I wrote it on the fly. I rewrote some of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to override `toString()` in your `ObjectA`,`ObjectB` class, which will return the attra,attrab, because, `ArrayList` automatically invokes the `toString` of the enclosing types to print string representation of elements.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13028580/985143

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking the `toString()` of your `ArrayList`. What you should do is to invoke the `toString()` of your class `world`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        world w = new world();
        System.out.println(w);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you may override toString() methods for Object A and Object B. Then you can simply iterate over your List and println the objects in your list as below.

```
    for (Object a : myList)
    System.out.println(a);
```